# Select pair numbers in SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

Database:

```
+------------+
|   Number   |
+------------+
| 0050000235 |
+------------+
| 5532003644 |
+------------+
| 1122330505 |
+------------+
| 1103220311 |
+------------+
| 1103000011 |
+------------+
| 1103020012 |
+------------+
```

To select numbers having pair of "0" 3 times I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM numbers
WHERE Number LIKE "%00%00%00%"
    OR Number LIKE "%00%0000%"
    OR Number LIKE "%0000%00%"
    OR Number LIKE "0000%00%"
    OR Number LIKE "%00%0000"   
    OR Number LIKE "00%0000%"
    OR Number LIKE "%0000%00"
    OR Number LIKE "%0000%00"
    OR Number LIKE "%000000%" 
    OR Number LIKE "000000%"
    OR Number LIKE "%000000"
```

This results me:

> 0050000235

But the way I am using, I think it's not a clean method.

**Question** How to fetch numbers *having 3 pairs* in it with clean SQL query?

The result will be:

> 0050000235, 5532003644, 1122330505, 1103220311 & 1103000011

Comment: The number `1103000011` has 4 pairs. Is this ok?

Comment: @forpas yes, that will do as it is having minimum 3 pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
where Number rlike '((00|11|22|33|44|55|66|77|88|99).*){3}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a series of numbers from 0 to 9 with UNION ALL and cross join to the table.
Each of these numbers will be doubled and replaced in the column of the table with an empty string. The difference in length of each replacement will be summed and if it is greater than 6 this means that there exist at least 3 pairs:

```
select 
  n.number
from (
  select 0 d union all select 1 d union all select 2  union all 
  select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all 
  select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
) s cross join numbers n
group by n.number                     
having sum(
  length(n.number) - length(replace(n.number, repeat(d, 2), '')) 
) >= 6
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vog9exkpK235ngo523uVK1/0).
Results:

```
| number     |
| ---------- |
| 0050000235 |
| 1103000011 |
| 1103220311 |
| 1122330505 |
| 5532003644 |
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using regular expressions?

```
where number regexp '00.*00.*00'
```

Or slightly shorter:

```
where number regexp '(00.*){3}'
```

You can readily generalize this to any two numbers:

```
where number regexp '([0-9]{2}.*){3}'
```

If you want to ensure exactly six `'0'` (as opposed to more):

```
where number regexp '^[^0]*00[^0]*00[^0]*00[^0]*$'
```

Comment: That's clean for 3 pair of 0, +1 for it. **How to fetch numbers having 3 pairs?** (irrespective of numbers [see the last result])

Comment: By using `LEFT(Number, 4)` we get first 4 numbers, what will the query for getting 4 numbers after leaving first 2 digits...?

Comment: @paran . . .  New questions should be asked as questions, instead of in comment.  In this case, though, you should review the string functions in MySQL.  The one you are referring to is `substr()`/`substring()`:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring.